# Display values from a one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a user table which has a one to many relationship with profiles, a user can have one profile:

The problem is that I want to update the user page, and among the data I want to display all the names of the profiles in a select option in a form and the user can choose his profile.

Here is my code :

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','route' => ['user.update', $user->id]]) !!}
    //.....
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="profil_id">Profile</label>
        <input type="text" name="profil_id" class="form-control" value="{{$user->profil->name}}">
        <select>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-info">
        <a href="{{ route('user.index')  }}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And my user controller update method :

```
public function update(UsersRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = Auth::user()->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

I have already set up the relationship in User and Profile models.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats not really a question and you are missing a lot of work.
1. Pass an array of profiles to the form and use foreach to display the options.
2. On the update method retrieve the profiles from the request and do something like foreach profile in request('profiles') Auth::user()->profiles()->create([ ' profile_name' => $profile]);

Answer (score 0):

> I have a user table which has a one to many relationship with
>   profiles, a user can have one profile

if a user can have one profile so relationship should be **[one to one](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)** not one to many

your question is that :

> I want to display all the names of the profiles in a select option

if profile model name is Profile use this code to show profile names in select box

```
<select name="profileid">
    @foreach (\App\Profile::All() as $record)
        <option value="{{ $record->id }}">{{ $record->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```